# Torn. Want to support LBS but they don't carry what I really want

Tags: weight, lbs, children

I live in a small town with one bike shop.  It is a good shop that I like a lot.  I am riding an bike that I built 15 years ago but I take it there and spend money on parts and maintenance.  I bought my kids 20" there.  When I can afford the bike I want to replace my bike I will almost certainly buy it from them.  But now I want to buy my elder son a 24" bike.  He is not a really powerful, aggressive rider.  The trails around here involve a lot of climbing.  I really think he would benefit from having a light bike.  There is one bike company that makes really light kids bikes (24" bike  <20 pounds).  The lightest 24" bike from the LBS is closer to 27 pounds.  That is a pretty big difference for somebody that weighs 65 pounds.

I'm just curious about how other people feel about situations like this and what they might do.

Comment: Have you tried asking if they can order one of those bikes or in case they can not if they can get a comparable one that they might not have in shop but can order from one of their suppliers? Shop space is a premium good and they tend to use it for bikes they can sell rather often instead of to kids bikes most people would possibly consider way too expensive for their kids.

Comment: Just order it online. I really don't know why you should feel bad by not ordering from a specific shop.

Comment: I've found that often if I order something through the LBS, they'll do pretty well at matching the real online price, since they won't charge me for shipping. (it's just one more thing in a big order from one of their suppliers).

Comment: "I'm just curious about how other people feel about situations like this and what they might do." -- This is by definition the sort of question that doesn't belong here. There are numerous chat groups that are appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem with my current MTB - I talked to the guy at my favorite LBS (I have a number of specialist but large chain bike shops close by, hes a small operator), and told him what I wanted (He stocked the brand, not the model, and it was end of season so stocks were short supply). I had seen it on the internet for a significant discount, told him that. He made a few phone calls and said "I cannot get one, and even if I could, I could not get close to that price. I am more than happy to assemble it for you if you need (clearly he was meaning for a charge)".

The LBS makes money from selling bikes, selling spares and servicing bikes. If you want to support your LBS, (as already suggested in the comments) ask him if he will order one in, and tell him what you have seen at what price. If he cannot or will not order a bike in, he should be more than happy to service it for you and will still sell you parts and accessories.

Comment: Sounds about right.  The bike in question is an Islabike.  I'm pretty sure there is only one distributor in the USA.

Answer (score 2):

You don't owe the bike shop your business. What I feel is not right is to use the bike shop for sizing or advice then go and buy it online to save a few dollars.

Consider the bike shop is the final point of assembly.  If the bike shop will order it for you then you basically get a free tune up.  Give the bike shop a chance to quote a number and if you can get it direct for a lot less then just tell them.

Not the same but a buddy of mine works as a golf pro.  He has people that try out clubs and then buy them online to save a few dollars.  Then if there is a problem they will come to him and he will tell them to deal with retailer.  They say but I don't want to mail them back.  And we will say then you should have bought them from me in the first place.

Comment: If you live in a small town and there's only one bike shop, while you don't "owe" it your business, if you enjoy having a local bike shop in town, then you ought to support it whether you owe it to them or not. If you always buy bikes and parts online and do all your service yourself, perhaps there's no need to support your LBS, but if you appreciate having a LBS in town, by all means, support the shop or you may find that it's not there the next time you really need it.

Comment: @Johnny What part of "give the shop a chance to quote a number" is not supporting your LBS?